# Is there any linear classifier with non-negative-weight constraints in Scikit-Learn?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I'm looking for

1. Scikit-Learn (or compatible to its API) implementation of
2. any linear model
3. classifier
4. that can constrain its weights (coefficient) to be positive (non-negative) as per the nature of the problem I'm solving.

So far, I cannot find any classifier... Is there any one? or what is the best alternative approach?

Comment: Maybe [here](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/18258/how-to-force-weights-to-be-non-negative-in-linear-regression) you can find an answer. Specifically, I found a referene to a [scipy implementation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.nnls.html) of __non-negative least squares__

Comment: @ronpi the answers in the DSSE thread (including mine) are for linear regression, not for a classifier.

Comment: I don't think non-negative weights make any sense in a classification setting, what exactly is the "nature of the problem you are solving"?